# Checking an array of PFUsers against another array of PFUsers SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have two arrays, `arrayA` and `arrayB`  which both have the same elements in which are PFUsers. Although `arrayB` is in the wrong order and needs to be in the order of `arrayA`. Can someone show me some code which could be able to do this?

Comment: I have tried nothing so far as I don't know how to do it at all...I am the point where I just have two arrays of PFUsers

Comment: If they have the same elements, why not just assign arrayB = arrayA? Or just make a copy of arrayA?

Comment: How would I do that? I need to make them become the same order....

Comment: I'm confused now. You have 2 different arrays of PFUsers and you know that both arrays contain exactly the same objects, just in different order? Aren't PFUser objects one-of-a-kind? (A unique user is represented single PFUser object, and there will never be 2 PFUser objects that refer to the same person?)

Comment: If I am right then just dump your second array and duplicate arrayA. A second array, arrayB, that contains the same objects as arrayA, in the same order, is essentially the same array.

Comment: Yes so e.g. I have two arrays with the same users in just in different order.

Comment: No I see your point but because this is part of a larger process

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert your arrays to sets and use the == operator to compare them, although sets don't allow duplicate objects. If your arrays contain duplicate objects and you want the count of different objects to effect array equality that won't work

You should be able to convert your arrays to NSCountedSet objects, which DO keep track of how many times an object is duplicated.

Comment: The question appears to be about sorting, not counting?

Comment: I took the question to be about comparing the arrays to see if they both contained the same objects, and how to do that even though the elements are in different orders.

Answer (score 0):

To sort array B into the order of array A (not particularly dealing with any duplicate objects in either array) you can sort B with a block that finds the indexes of those objects (or objects with the same `objectId`) and then returns the comparison of the indexes.

Comment: Thanks, can you expand with some code so I have a better understanding?